# Is there a R function which calculates the total french fama alpha in a data base per fund per year?

Tags: r, regression, alpha, beta

Current code:

```
alpha_function <- function(x){
  group_by(wficn, caldt) %>%
  lm(mktrf~excess_return, data = CRSP_database) %>%
  tidy() %>%
  [[1]]$estimate
  return()
}
```

Data:
date, fundno, mtna, mret, mnav, mktrf, smb, hml, umd, rf

Needed is a database showing the total alpha per fund per year.
Or the beta of one fundno per year.

Comment: Can you rephrase? I'm having trouble parsing out your code and what you're asking for.

Comment: We have a data base in which we need to find the beta's and alpha's for each separate fund for each seperate year. Currently using the following code:                                                 
      Returns_Database <- CRSP_Database %>%
  select(Wficn, caldt, Excess_Return, mktrf, smb, hml, umd, rf, mret ) %>%
  nest(data = !c("Wficn", "caldt")) %>%
  mutate(model = map(data ~ alpha_function)) %>%
  mutate( model, tidy)%>%
  unnest(model)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a `!` in the `nest()` call.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below, but again it would be easier to help if you could provide an example of your data set to test it on.

```
alpha_function <- function(x){
  CRSP_database %>%
    group_by(wficn, caldt) %>%
    lm(mktrf~excess_return, data = .x) %>%
    tidy() %>%
    pluck("estimate")
}
```